# How to get Python to add the current time and date automatically as the filename?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am trying to get python to automatically add the current time and date as a filename after it finishes with running the report its designed to.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  It should be simple to generate a time stamp string.

Comment: I have been trying...I got it to save the report as soon as the report is finished but I need to add the name of the folder, which should be something like - XYZ Report 19 Sept 2018...that bit I cant figure

Comment: The problem is adding the current date automatically to the file name once the report had finished and before its saved

Comment: Post your code please, it will help us help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer is:

```
    import time
    import xlwt
    import csv

    date_string = time.strftime("%Y%m%d %H.%M")
```

#### if saving to CSV document

```
    data_output = []
    with open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\File Name' + date_string + '.csv', 'a+') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        for data in data_output:
            w.writerow(data)
      f.close()
```

#### if saving to Excel document

```
    df.to_excel('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\File Name' + date_string + '.xlsx')
```

#### if saving to Txt document

```
    df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\File Name' + date_string + '.txt')
```

Comment: I wanted to have a datafile to be saved after my script finished running in a way that it was easy to identify the file and contect. I run my script a few times a day yielding different outputs. This way I can have  an automatic filing system. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Get current date from [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module using `datetime.date.today()`, use [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to parse it to your required format and add it to your filename string.

```
import datetime
filename = 'XYZ Report {0}.txt'
current_date = datetime.date.today().strftime('%d %b %Y')
filename = filename.format(current_date)
# filename = XYZ Report 19 Sep 2018.txt
with open(filename) as file_obj:
# File writing logic
```

Comment: The call to `format` isn't strictly necessary; you could just define `filename` directly with `filename = datetime.date.today().strftime('XYZ Report %d %b %Y.txt')`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can pass the `date` object directly to `format`, skipping the call to `strftime`: `"XYZ Report {0:%b %d %Y}.txt".format(datetime.date.today())`.